# Yammer Embed suddenly not working in IE when Compatibility View is enabled

Tags: javascript, yammer

As of yesterday, our employees no longer see the Yammer Embed feed within our intranet site. In its place is white space - no errors on the page. We found that disabling compatibility view in IE fixes the issue - however, Yammer Embed was working just fine in compatibility view before yesterday. When compatibility view is enabled, we also see this error:

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'querySelector' 
>   platform_embed.js, line 1 character 3802

We are curious if code has changed on the Yammer end recently that would be causing this issue?

Comment: Are you rendering IE in a particular mode using the `X-UA-Compatible` meta tag perhaps? Sounds like [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) is not supported. That was in IE 8+ though. Can't imagine you would render in 7 standards. Just a thought...

Comment: Thanks War10ck. It turns out that turning off compatibility mode in IE does fix our issue. However, Yammer Embed was working fine for all these users before yesterday. We'd like to know if something changed on the Yammer side that might have impacted us before we start rolling out IE config settings to our thousands of employees. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Compatibility View isn't recommended because it forces Yammer Embed to run in an unsupported mode. There is some information in the Embed documentation about [browser support](http://developer.yammer.com/connect/). Yammer stopped supporting IE 7 last year, and as a result new changes are deployed with newer browser versions in mind.

There have been no aggressive attempts to prevent IE 7 from rendering Embed, but this recent set of changes means that it won't run unless you can set your hosting page to use a higher IE version. Please bear in mind that IE 8 support has a relatively close end of life, so you are better targeting IE 9 support in your pages for more longevity.